# Devise email encryption

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to encrypt email using ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor on devise but some problem.

1. sign-in is denied (error: Invalid Email or password.)
2. same email is registered

---

**What i did so far**

1. I checked my record which is encrypted and decrypted and email is correct.
2. I changed from 'after_find' to 'after_initialize' and get error.

   'ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage' when I sign-in.
3. I try email confirmation setting and get error.

   ' Recipient address rejected: need fully-qualified address' when I sign-in.

---

**My Guess**

decryption timing is not good.

Which means encrypted email might be used in devise gem not decrypted.

---

**My code**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  before_save :encrypt_value
  after_find  :decrypt_value

  def encrypt_value
    self.email = encrypt(self.email)
  end

  def decrypt_value
    self.email = decrypt(self.email) if email.present?
  end


  def encrypt(value)

    @SECURE = 'HOGEHOGEHOGEHOGEHOGEHOGEHOGEHOGE'
    @CIPHER = 'aes-256-cbc'

    crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(@SECURE, @CIPHER)
    crypt.encrypt_and_sign(value)

  end

  def decrypt(value)

    @SECURE = 'HOGEHOGEHOGEHOGEHOGEHOGEHOGEHOGE'
    @CIPHER = 'aes-256-cbc'

    crypt = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(@SECURE, @CIPHER)
    crypt.decrypt_and_verify(value)

  end

end
```

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a well known issue.

And if you took the look at their repository => https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/939

You can see that the issue is particularly with the Devise initialiser. It needs to have a valid email address, otherwise it won't work.

So under `config/initializers` find the `devise.rb`, and change the `"please-change-me@config-initializers-devise.com"` property to a valid email address.

Comment: My devise setting seems to be correct except encryption.
I think 'Recipient address rejected: need fully-qualified address' is shown because of my encrypted email value is not decrypted when sending confirmation.